# Laravel - 1215 Cannot add foreign constraint

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I am trying to link up to three tables together but when I run my migration (using artisan) I keep getting an error:

> General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `stores` add constraint `stores_sale_id_foreign` foreign key (`sale_id`) references `bikes` (`id`))

Here is my migration file for stores:

```
    class CreateStoresTable extends Migration {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('store_name');
                $table->string('city');
                $table->string('manager');
                $table->integer('sale_id')->unsigned();
                $table->timestamps();
            });

            Schema::table('stores', function ($table){
                $table->foreign('sale_id')->references('id')->on('bikes');
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down() {
            Schema::dropIfExists('stores');
        }
    }
```

**store model:**

```
    class Store extends Model {
        use HasFactory;

        protected $table = 'stores';
        protected $fillable = ['store_name', 'city', 'manager', 'sale_id'];
    }
```

Edit:
**bikes migration:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBikesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bikes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('make');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('bikes');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add bikes table migration source code

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact ive used sale_id for both the accessories table and stores table?

Comment: did you try foreignId method https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Instead of increments try `$table->id()`or `$table->bigIncrements('id')` for both tables.
Because the id column will then have the right type.

You will also need to set your foreign key  column to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('sale_id');` to set the right column type fore the foreign constraint.

And you will have to make sure that your bikes migration runs before your stores migration.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
class CreateStoresTable extends Migration {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('store_name');
                $table->string('city');
                $table->string('manager');
                $table->integer('sale_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->foreign('sale_id')->references('id')->on('bikes')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down() {
            Schema::dropIfExists('stores');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: ```$table->unsignedInteger('sale_id')->nullable();```  try this

Answer (score -1):

**Use this code**

```
class CreateStoresTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('store_name');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('manager');
            $table->unsignedInteger('sale_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('sale_id')->references('id')->on('bikes')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stores');
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure there should not be a mismatch in foreign key field types.

- Either change original migration from increments() to just
  bigIncrements()
- Or in your foreign key column do unsignedBigInteger() instead of unsignedInteger().

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: What is the type of `bikes.id` in your `bike` table?

Comment: $table->increments('id'). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing, let me see.

Comment: I commented out the two lines for sale_id in the store migration and it seemed to work fine even though i have the same code linking another table to the bikes table.

Comment: When the code is commented out it works but when i uncomment it, the migration doesn't work again

Comment: I have edited the code now, use it and see you get an error or not?

Comment: Your both `bike.id` and also your foreign key in your store table is `integer`, it is confusing~

Comment: I am very new to this stuff sorry